# getting index out of range in numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I have a weird cellModel in my tableView like this

```
   fileprivate enum CellModel {
    case search
    case categories
    case switcher
    case wishes
}

fileprivate enum HeaderModel {
    typealias CellType = CellModel
    case search
    case categories
    case switcher
    case wishes


    var cellModels: [MAWishesViewController.CellModel] {
        switch self {
        case .search: return [.search]
        case .categories: return [.categories]
        case .switcher: return [.switcher]
        case .wishes: return [.wishes]
        }
    }
}

private var wishes = [Wish]()
private var categories = [Category]()

private let models:[CellModel] = [.search, .categories, .switcher, .wishes]
private let HeaderModels: [HeaderModel] = [.search, .categories, .switcher, .wishes]
```

and here is my delegate and dataSource methods : ) I use model with enum and I started think this is bad idea!

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return models.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  let header = HeaderModels[section]
    switch header {
    case .categories:
        return 1
    case .search:
        return 1
    case .switcher:
        return 1
    case .wishes:
        return self.wishes.count
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let model = HeaderModels[indexPath.section].cellModels[indexPath.row]


    switch model {
    case .search:
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SearchTableViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as? SearchTableViewCell {

            return cell
        }
    case .categories:
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CategoriesTableViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as? CategoriesTableViewCell {
            cell.collectionView.delegate = self
            cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
            return cell
        }
    case .switcher:
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SwitcherTableViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as? SwitcherTableViewCell {

            return cell
        }
    case .wishes:
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WishTableViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as? WishTableViewCell {

            let wish = self.wishes[indexPath.row]
            cell.pictureImageView.image = UIImage(named: wish.image!)
            cell.nameLabel.text = wish.name
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = wish.description
            return cell
        }
    }

    return UITableViewCell.init()
}
```

And I got "INDEX OUT Of RANGE. All I want is to return `wishes.count` in section called `.wishes`

Also I get out of index in `cellForRowAt` method. So what the problem could be?

Comment: your question is not clear .. share cellForRow method

Comment: where you are getting crash ...

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the numberOfRowsInSection method and inspect your HeaderModels array to make sure it really contains the correct number of items.

Comment: I checked your code and there is no crash. Just make sure you have have registered all the cells with tableView.